# How to create a custom Spring LoginMessageInterceptor?

Tags: spring, authentication, message, interceptor

How can I create and register my own `LoginMessageInterceptor` in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure have you solved this. My example is based on Spring-Flex. From [Spring-Flex reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.5.x/reference/html/index.html#message-interceptors) and [Spring Flex Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-flex/docs/1.5.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/flex/security3/LoginMessageInterceptor.html#getAuthenticationResult%28%29), have your class implements MessageInterceptor or override the default class provided by Spring, register it with desired **position** attribute of the **message-interceptor** configuration tag. Example for my case:

```
<bean id="myMessageInterceptor" class="my.mimos.kec.ooes.security.LoginMessageInterceptor"/>
<flex:message-broker mapping-order="1">
    <flex:message-interceptor position="LOGIN_MESSAGE_INTERCEPTOR" ref="myMessageInterceptor"/>
    <flex:mapping pattern="/messagebroker/*"/>
    <flex:message-service
        default-channels="my-streaming-amf,my-longpolling-amf,my-polling-amf" />
    <flex:secured />
</flex:message-broker>
```

Thanks.